# Could not initialize class com.ibm.ws.ffdc.FFDCFilter

Tags: websphere

Starting IBM Websphere in Eclipse Mars, always gives this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to FrontServer...".
Could not initialize class com.ibm.ws.ffdc.FFDCFilter
```

I'm using Websphere Version 7.0

Any idea how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to run Eclipse with IBM JVM. Change it in eclipse.ini.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It doesn't work.

Comment: So what is your entry in eclipse.ini and which IBM JVM version you did try?

Comment: I had added this entry in eclipse.ini file "-vm C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin\javaw.exe", restarted eclipse and server, but was still getting same error. IBM JVM version is 1.6

Comment: Try to  add IBM's sdk to "installed JREs" and check as default in preferences. Also make sure you are using WebSphere traditional server adapter not Liberty.

Comment: I already have these two things done. IBM's sdk is marked default and I'm using traditional adapter.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are some solutions, like upgrading Eclipse, changing to IBM JRE etc.

But the issue is related to the ORB jar that is missing.

The `FFDCFilter` error can be solved as described in "*RMI Connection Type*" found in this technote [IBM Support page - swg21999577](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21999577)

The `com.ibm.ws.orb_X jar` is missing and that causes the `FFDCFilter` issue. It is the result of using the non-IBM JDK. **The reason why** this jar is not included as part of WDT is because this jar conflicts with the IBM JDK case.

### Solution

> 1. **copy** the orb jar, I think your version might be `com.ibm.ws.orb_7.0.0.jar` (look in your AppServer folder) **to** e.g. c:\lib
> 2. Add the following line at end of your eclipse.ini `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\lib`

(You could also copy the orb jar into your java jre endorsed library folder.)

See [IBM Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/wasdtfe?topic=issues-unable-initialize-class-comibmwsffdcffdcfilter) with more information.

Comment: this works with WAS 8.5 running in Eclipse Neon, thanks!

Comment: Also works on WAS 9.0. Jar is named: com.ibm.ws.orb_9.0.jar.  Eclipse Oxygen.

Comment: This worked with WAS9 spring tool suite as well. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It is a known problem and is caused because the non-IBM JRE is missing certain classes. To work around this problem:

1. Go to `/runtimes/com.ibm.ws.orb_VERSION.jar` check jar is exist OR go to `/lib/com.ibm.ws.orb_VERSION.jar` check jar is exist where is the jar exist we have to copy the path
2. Add the following line in `eclipse.ini`:

> ```
> -Djava.endorsed.dirs=<the directory where 
>         com.ibm.ws.orb_VERSION.jar was copied to in step 1>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

My solution its basic and works for me. Close eclipse and reopen it.

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps for resolution.
Go into IBM Web Sphere  runtimes directory .
Copy the orb jar the version suffix will state your WebShphere Version.
Create a folder in your choice of drive and and copy the file .In my case it is C:\IBMJars\lib
Go Into eclipse installation folder and right above the eclipse.exe file open up the ini file in notepad and add the command at the end of the file.
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\IBMJars\lib
Restart eclipse and you should be good to go.