# An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to WAS 8559 ..."

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, websphere-8

I got following error while starting the server.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Publishing to WAS 8559 ...".
Could not initialize class com.ibm.ws.ffdc.FFDCFilter
```

**Eclipse** Java EE IDE for Web Developers **Version**: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

IBM **WebSphere** Application Server for Developers 8.5.5.9

I tried some methods posted in stackoverflow. But it doesn't work.
e.g.[could-not-initialize-class-com-ibm-ws-ffdc-ffdcfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240285/could-not-initialize-class-com-ibm-ws-ffdc-ffdcfilter)

1.added this entry in eclipse.ini file "-vm C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin\javaw.exe", restarted eclipse and server;
2.Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs
[image]

Do you have any suggestion about this problem?

Comment: See [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/288639/websphere-traditional-v85-eclipse-plugin-problems.html) and consider to update your Eclipse IDE + JDK.

Comment: This link provides two methods, one is add "-vm IBM_SDK_PATH" , one is add IBM's SDK to "installed JREs". I tried both. So you mean the only way to solve this problem is updating the IDE and JDK?

Comment: Is this a bug in Eclipse?

Comment: @Dustbreak To avoid misunderstandings: Did you replace _IBM_SDK_PATH_ with the path of the IBM SDK (see [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM))?

Comment: Thank you howlger, I tried many times according to this link. But failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some solutions, like upgrading Eclipse, changing to IBM JRE etc.

But the issue is related to the ORB jar that is missing.

The `FFDCFilter` error can be solved as described in "*RMI Connection Type*" found in this technote [IBM Support page - swg21999577](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21999577)

The `com.ibm.ws.orb jar` is missing and that causes the `FFDCFilter` issue. It is the result of using the non-IBM JDK. **The reason why** this jar is not included as part of WDT is because this jar conflicts with the IBM JDK case.

### Solution

> 1. **copy** the orb jar, I think your version might be `com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar` (look in your AppServer folder) **to** e.g. c:\lib
> 2. Add the following line at end of your eclipse.ini `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\lib`

(You could also copy the orb jar into your java jre endorsed library folder.)

See [forum post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=b3048f8a-b07d-4950-afcb-7c58eef079b7) with more information.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

I followed MrSimpleMind's solution and this worked for me. I copied the com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar from
**C:\Program Files(x86)\IBM\Websphere\AppServer\bin\ProfileManagement\eclipse64** to **C:\lib**. The only thing I did differently and just to be on the safe side was to update the eclipse.ini in all locations where I found it. I shut down the eclipse, restarted and the publish worked after this change. Thanks MrSimpleMind